# How to access locked excel files using apache poi

Tags: java, excel

I am having excel files which are locked i am not able to access them normally with microsoft excel software, if i do chmod 755 to the excel i am able to access the excel file with microsoft excel software

If i try to read excel file with workbook.createinput(file) i am getting is it an excel file error

> java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: The supplied POIFSFileSystem does not contain a BIFF8 'Workbook' entry. Is it really an excel file?

so how to execute the file with chmod 755 and then read with workbook.createinput(file)

Comment: can you share some code with us?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33258417/workbookfactory-createinput-is-throwing-your-inputstream-was-neither-an-ole2

Answer (score -1):

Check out this code (WorkbookFactory):

```
java.io.File file = new File("yourFile");
org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.Workbook workBook = org.apache.poi.ss.usermodel.WorkbookFactory.create(file);
```

Comment: i am already having file i want to make it readable using chmod 755